# Android process needed for location

Tags: cyanogenmod, permissions

I am testing the Privacy Guard feature of CyanogenMod. I disabled almost all of every app's permissions (with 'Show built-int apps' enabled) to then enable only those I know I need. The problem that emerged was that for example my Phone and Messaging apps lost ability to read contacts. Even when I allowed them to read them. To fix that problem I needed to give proper permissions to the Contacts Storage - seems obvious once you know that. Now I have similar problem with location. I allow apps to use it but they cannot access it. I tried a couple of apps so I assume that this is problem is only connected with permissions, not the app itself.

My question is what permissions of which (probably built-in) app I need to enable to let other apps (which have proper permission) access my location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

• FusedLocation - for fused network and gps switch

Different devices use different apps other than Fused

Mine is Qualcomm Location

Comment: Thank you, I thought that the app is the same for all CMs. For my phone the app is... Google Play services - phone is Nexus 4. Google won this time.